# Why is Ubuntu 11.10 64bit using all my memory?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, vaio, memory-leak

I have a Sony Vaio VPCZ122GX with 4GB RAM,Nvidia Cards.
I install ubuntu 11.10 64 bit.
I am currently open : 1 Tab Firefox, Virtual Box with 1 WinXP ~700 RAM, 1 terminal top. That's all.
But Memory used is 3.5 GB.
I think there must be memory leak while I can see in top: Virtualbox ( 2 process: 696MB + 37MB), Firefox 33MB.
Can you help me to fix it. I try googling an searching in askubuntu but no luck.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the output of `free -m` or a screenshot of top or how you are looking at your memory.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of Top:
http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/6194/topuy.png

Comment: Could it be RAM caching? http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Yeah, may be that is right. I can see 
-/+ buffers/cache:       1442       2192 .
It means 2192 GB RAM is currently Free. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: @DaltonMiller you should post that as an answer, and let Summer Nguyen accept it. This helps both of your reputations, and makes answers easier to find for new users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by [Linux caching your RAM](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

Comment: Please include some details from the link in your post as if the link were to stop working, your answer may not help future users.